# How do I filter through a list of objects that contains lists?

Tags: java, filter, java-8, java-stream

Imagine I have a json like the following:

```
[
    {
        field: string,
        roles: [
            {
                id: int,
                providedFor: int
            },
            {
                id: int,
                providedFor: int
            },
            ...
        ]
    },
    {
        field: string,
        roles: [
            {
                id: int,
                providedFor: int
            },
            {
                id: int,
                providedFor: int
            },
            ...
        ]
    },
    {
        field: string,
        roles: [
            {
                id: int,
                providedFor: int
            },
            {
                id: int,
                providedFor: int
            },
            ...
        ]
    }
]
```

And this is parse into a list of objects and call this list providers.
How can I go about filtering/streaming this list, find the correct provider then breaking out?

I've tried something like the following:

```
providers.parallelStream().filter(p -> p.getRoles().parallelStream().filter(r -> r.getProvidedFor.equal("something")).findFirst());
```

Comment: What do you want to return exactly? How about showing us Java classes, with names, rather than anonymous JSON objects?

Comment: `flatMap` is your friend!

Comment: doh! right, as i loop through the list of objects, when the providedFor matches, i need to return the field. @BoristheSpider could you show an example? i just started working with java 8.

Comment: First could you do as JBNizet asks, and provide a class structure and also a more detailed description of what you want to do.

Comment: a parallelstream inside a parallelstream is probably a bad idea as it could significantly deteriorate performance. I would parallelise the outer stream but leave the inner stream sequential.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you have not provided any classes I have experimented with the following structure:

```
class Field {
    String field;
    List<Role> roles;

    Field(String field, List<Role> roles) {
        this.field = field;
        this.roles = roles;
    }
}

class Role {
    int id;
    int providedFor;

    Role(int id, int providedFor) {
        this.id = id;
        this.providedFor = providedFor;
    }
}
```

`Field` is the outer object and `Role` is the inner object. So, if you build up a `List` of `Field` objects like this:

```
final List<Field> fields = Arrays.asList(
        new Field("f11", Arrays.asList(new Role(11, 11), new Role(11, 12))),
        new Field("f22", Arrays.asList(new Role(22, 22), new Role(22, 23))),
        new Field("f33", Arrays.asList(new Role(33, 33), new Role(33, 34))));
```

And, you are searching for `something`:

```
int something = 22;
```

You can filter out your `Role` by using the `flatMap` method like this:

```
final Optional<Role> first = fields.stream()
        .flatMap(f -> f.roles.stream())          // Chain all "substreams" to one stream
        .filter(r -> r.providedFor == something) // Check for the correct object
        .findFirst();                            // Find the first occurrence
```

Note that if `providedFor` is not a primitive but some kind of `Object` the `equals` method should be used instead.

If you are instead looking for the `Field` class you can simply nest the streams like this:

```
final Optional<Field> firstField = fields.stream()
        .filter(f -> f.roles.stream()                       // Nested stream
                .anyMatch(r -> r.providedFor == something)) // Return true if present
        .findFirst();                                       // Find the first Field object (findAny can be used here as well if "any" hit is ok)
```

This will return the first `Field` that matches the provided `Role.providedFor`.

From the [flatMap JavaDocs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#flatMap-java.util.function.Function-):

> Returns a stream consisting of the results of replacing each element of this stream with the contents of a mapped stream produced by applying the provided mapping function to each element.

Basically you are *chaining* nested streams to one stream.

In the end, the `findfirst` method returns the first match. This means that there may be no match and therefore an `Optional` is returned. The `Optional` class has method for retrieving the underlying object and checking if it exists (`get()` and `isPresent()`). Check out the [Optional JavaDocs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Optional.html) for more info.

Comment: sorry, bit slow. but pretty much what you described, i will try this out later. thanks!

Comment: what you have works, but it is returning a Role object, i need the "field". im not even sure if what im asking is doable, i just thought i could try it out with java 8

Comment: @yaojiang, I have updated the example to include that as well.

Comment: You don’t need to call `.findFirst().isPresent()`. First of all, if you just want to know whether there is *any* match, you should not query for the *first* match as in this case `findAny()` might be more efficient, but if you are not interested in the actual value but just want to know whether there is any match, use `anyMatch(condition)` which replaces the entire `filter(condition).findFirst().isPresent()`.